# how to switch views according to command

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a main view and many usercontrols.

The main view contains a two column grid, with the first column filled with a listbox whose datatemplate consists of a usercontrol and the second column filled with another usercontrol. These two usercontrols have the same datacontext.

**MainView:**

```
<Grid>
    //Column defs
    ...
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemSource="{Binding FooList}">
        ...
        <DataTemplate>  
            <Views: FooView1 />  
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FooList.Count}" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Views: FooView2 />
    </StackPanel>
<Grid>
```

**FooView1:**

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Title}">
</UserControl>
```

**FooView2:**

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail1}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail2}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail3}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail4}">
</UserControl>
```

*I've no IDE here. Excuse me if there is any syntax error*

When the user clicks on a button. These two usercontrols have to be replaced by another two usercontrols, so the datacontext changes, the main ui remaining the same.

*ie, FooView1 by BarView1 and FooView2 by BarView2*

In short i want to bind this view changes in mainview to my command *(command from Button)*

How can i do this?

Also tell me if i could merge the usercontrol pairs, so that only one view exists for each viewmodel

ie, FooView1 and FooView2 into FooView and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Though I am still not sure whether I got you, I suggest the following.

In your example it looks like you want to show the details of the *Foo* object. The datacontext stays the same. Maybe you can set Visibility-Flags in your viewmodel to decide what you want to display. This can be done using the command that is executed by your button.

**FooView:**

```
<UserControl> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Title}"
               Visibility="{Binding ShowTitle}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail1}"
               Visibility="{Binding ShowDetails}"> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail2}"
               Visibility="{Binding ShowDetails}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail3}"
               Visibility="{Binding ShowDetails}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail4}"
               Visibility="{Binding ShowDetails}">
</UserControl>
```

Is this a possible solution?

If you want to change the datatemplate you might do something like this:

**FooView (2nd version)**

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Title}">
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate2">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail1}"> 
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail2}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail3}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Detail4}">
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="Default">
       <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo.ShowFooView}" Value="1" >
               <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource dataTemplate1}" />
           <DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.ShowFooView}" Value="2" >
               <Setter Property="Template" Foo="{StaticResource dataTemplate2}" />
           </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</UserControl>
```

The idea is, that depending on the property *Foo.ShowFooView* you decide which data template should be used. Of course the type *Foo* should implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* to notify the UI.

Comment: not exactly, but you're in my way. Instead of setting visibility to child elements, i've already implemented this for the entire UserControl (FooView2). My Question is 'Is there a way i could dynamically change the datatemplate also for ListView (FooView1)?'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't get the point. To answer your question you need to provide more information.

1. Do you want to change your datacontext by replacing a usercontrol?
2. Why don't you use different datatemplates for different target types?
3. Maybe you can provide some code snippets.